# Setting multiple variables for one column in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to set several variables in a stored procedure in SQL Server.
Currently, I use individual `SELECT` statements to set each variable.  I don't know if there is a better/ more efficient way of doing it.
This is a sample of 2 variables but there are 8 variables total.

```
DECLARE @source nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @target nvarchar(250) 

SET @source = (SELECT Value FROM ApplicationSetting WHERE Key = 'Source')
SET @target = (SELECT Value FROM ApplicationSetting WHERE Key = 'Target')
```

Currently, I use 8 individual select statements to set each variable.
Is this the most efficient way to set this many variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single `select` we can assign both the variables using conditional aggregate

Try this way

```
DECLARE @source NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @target NVARCHAR(250)

SELECT @source = Max(CASE WHEN KEY = 'Source' THEN Value END),
       @target = Max(CASE WHEN KEY = 'Target' THEN Value END)
FROM   ApplicationSetting
WHERE  KEY IN( 'Source', 'Target' )
```

Comment: Perfect!  I could not figure out how to use `CASE`...adding `MAX` was the ticket.  Thanks!